# cakephp creates misspelled model class and it's filename

Tags: cakephp, naming-conventions, conventions

I have a database table named 'abuses'. While baking the application the bake command named it's controller classname as "abuses" and filename as "abuses_controller.php" but when I baked the model the filename was "Abus.php" and classname was "Abus".

Is that a bug in cakePHP ? or did I miss something ?

Has anyone encountered the same problem yet ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add your custom inflection rules if the Cake Inflector gets it wrong (it's only human, and a singular '~e' is probably uncommon for a plural '~es'):
http://book.cakephp.org/view/953/Inflections

Comment: +1 I'd also just write in a custom inflection rule for this word.

Answer (score 2):

its due to inflections check this http://book.cakephp.org/view/953/Inflections

Comment: but "abuses" is an english word and it is wrongly pluralizing it while baking the application. My question was if it is a bug in cakephp ?

Comment: cakephp will be using regex to singularize and pluralize words so it will recognize both abuses and boxes as one

Comment: I don't think so the class will singularize the word "boxes" as "box" and "abuses" as "abus". It removes the 'es' from the word for singularization. Give this code "pr(Inflector::singularize("abuses"));" a try.!

Comment: what im telling is they could have used a regex to remove the last 2 letters 'es' in a word and also when i looked in cake/libs/inflector.php in the document section they have said' Inflector pluralizes and singularizes English nouns.' abuse is a noun abuses i dont know

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at CakePHP's [Inflector](http://book.cakephp.org/view/491/Inflector) class.